# How to find who accessed(ip log) phpmyadmin in xampp version 5.6.23?

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am using xampp 5.6.23. Now I have requirement that I have to find who accessed(by ip address) phpmyadmin.

Comment: I have to track down,who make change in phpmyadmin  other than me by some trick...no reason to down vote

Answer (score 0):

dont give up friends,finally I found solution..its possible..
go to
xammp/phpmyadmin/index.php

put this code in it

```
//==========ip log who accessed phpmyadmin===========

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta'); 
$ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$txt = $ip."=>".$time."%%%%%%%%";
$myfile = file_put_contents('newfile.txt', $txt.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | 
LOCK_EX);
//=====================================================
```

and create newfile.txt in phpmyadmin folder..you will get ip log with time,date......best of luck!!!